# Marbles into bins, where bins must have *at least* a certain number of marbles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say we have $2n$ indistinguishable marbles to be distributed into $n \geq 3$ labeled bins.  How many arrangements are there such that 2 bins have at least 2 marbles each, and the remaining bins have at least $1$ marble each?

I originally attempted to solve this problem by assigning all bins to have 1 marble each, then choosing 2 of the $n$ bins to get a second marble.  I then attempted to distribute the remaining marbles using multichoose/stars and bars, but I realized this could lead to over-counting of scenarios.

What might be a better approach to solving this problem?  Thank you!

Comment: The number of arrangements should be the number of arrangements in which every bin has at least one marble, minus the number of arrangements in which all but one bin has exactly one marble. Since there are more marbles than bins, at least one must have two or more marbles. The only way that you don't have two bins with two or more marbles is if every bin has one marble, except one has all the rest.

Comment: Maybe easier to count all assignments, then subtract all unsatisfying assignments. I think those with no 2 bins having at least 2 marbles is reasonably countable...

Comment: @kccu:  I would make that an answer.  OP asked for an approach and that is a good one

Comment: @RossMillikan The only reason I didn't is because I haven't worked the problem out yet. It seems like it would be fairly easy to compute, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @kccu:  yes, the first is a stars and bars problem.  The second you choose the bin that has most of the marbles and you are done.